# Select events that represent the most recent work on roads

Tags: sql, overlapping-features, oracle-dbms, linear-referencing, oracle-spatial

*I have a question on Stack Overflow where I ask about [Selecting events that represent the most recent work on roads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081473/select-events-that-represent-the-most-recent-work-on-roads). So far, I have been provided an [answer that seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52087448/5576771), although it is **quite complicated**.*

*The question has been proposed to a non-spatially-minded crowd.
As such, I would like to knowingly cross post on GIS SE, to see what the spatial & linear referencing crowds have to say about it.*

*I know cross posting is generally considered to be offensive, but if you consider this [comment from Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012/354903), I'm hoping that my question is **good enough:***

> ...this can be OK, so long as the question is tailored to each
>   audience on the different sites and is materially different in each
>   case.

---

**So here it goes:**

I have a non-spatial `road_events` table:

```
create table road_events (
    event_id number(4,0),
    road_id number(4,0),
    year number(4,0),
    from_meas number(10,2),
    to_meas number(10,2),
    total_road_length number(10,2)
    );

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (1,1,2020,25,50,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (2,1,2000,25,50,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (3,1,1980,0,25,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (4,1,1960,75,100,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (5,1,1940,1,100,100);

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (6,2,2000,10,30,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (7,2,1975,30,60,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (8,2,1950,50,90,100);

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (9,3,2050,40,90,100);

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (10,4,2040,0,200,200);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (11,4,2013,0,199,200);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (12,4,2001,0,200,200);

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (13,5,1985,50,70,300);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (14,5,1985,10,50,300);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (15,5,1965,1,301,300);
commit;

select * from road_events;
```

---

```
  EVENT_ID    ROAD_ID       YEAR  FROM_MEAS    TO_MEAS TOTAL_ROAD_LENGTH
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------
         1          1       2020         25         50               100
         2          1       2000         25         50               100
         3          1       1980          0         25               100
         4          1       1960         75        100               100
         5          1       1940          1        100               100

         6          2       2000         10         30               100
         7          2       1975         30         60               100
         8          2       1950         50         90               100

         9          3       2050         40         90               100

        10          4       2040          0        200               200
        11          4       2013          0        199               200
        12          4       2001          0        200               200

        13          5       1985         50         70               300
        14          5       1985         10         50               300
        15          5       1965          1        301               300
```

---

**I want to select the events that represent the most recent work on each road.**

This is a tricky operation, because the events **often pertain to only a portion of the road**. This means that I can't simply select the most recent event per road; I  need to only select the most recent ***event mileage*** that doesn't overlap.

**This is a classic [linear referencing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm) problem.** It is normally done with geoprocessing operations in ArcGIS Desktop (or equivalent). However, I need to do it as part of existing, complex SQL queries/workflows (on-the-fly).

This is what the result would look like:

```
 EVENT_ID    ROAD_ID       YEAR  TOTAL_ROAD_LENGTH   EVENT_LENGTH
---------- ---------- ----------  -----------------   ------------
         1          1       2020                100             25
         3          1       1980                100             25
         4          1       1960                100             25
         5          1       1940                100             25

         6          2       2000                100             20
         7          2       1975                100             30
         8          2       1950                100             30

         9          3       2050                100             50

        10          4       2040                200            200

        13          5       1985                300             20
        14          5       1985                300             40
        15          5       1965                300            240
```

---

**Question:**

**What would it take to do this in SQL?**

*I'm hoping, as spatially & LRS minded people, that we might have a unique perspective on the problem, and come up with some interesting results.*

Related question: [Select where number range does not overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729896/select-where-number-range-does-not-overlap)

Comment: I mentioned some [*proposed logic*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZH5B.png) in the Stack Overflow post. However, it was suggested that it hurt more than it helped, so I've omitted it from the GIS SE question. With that said, it's available if you want it.

Comment: Do you have a spatial table or layer for your roads? Or is it strictly non-spatial data that you have? If it's the latter I don't think the solution can be much simpler than the aswer you already got, that is the way I would do it as well. Maybe use GROUP BY and MIN functions instead of the "lead over partition" function and see if it changes performance.

Comment: @FSimardGIS Yes, I have an M-enabled `sde.st_geometry` spatial table as a road inventory. The common field is `road_id`. Do you think it would help? `sde.st_geometry` does not have linear referencing functions. I do not have Oracle Spatial.

Comment: Are you open to using, for example, another software (GIS software) to populate a table in your DB from a model? Also some nice visuals could be created by such a model. If you are limited to views/functions, etc inside your DB only, then I would go with the solution on StackOverflow, I don't think any performance gain can be achieved by doing otherwise with Oracle Non-Spatial functions only.

Comment: @FSimardGIS You make some good points. However, yes, I think I am *"limited to views/functions, etc inside my DB only"*. Doing stuff in models would be static, which is not what I'm looking for. I've gotten a couple more answers on Stack Overflow, and think you're right--I'll just go with one of them. While the SQL might be long, the performance is surprisingly good.

Comment: I think you can leave it open, if others have ideas then they can post them here. But I think the pure SQL solution should work fine here indeed.